# how to send multiple values to web service for storing in database

Tags: android, android-webservice

I am using an web service to store multiple values in database. I have created the code but was not able to store the values in remote database. There is no error in the code but instead of the the values are not storing in database.

Here is my code:

```
public String registerDoctor(String MethodName,Pojo p)
{
    try 
    {
        SOAP_ACTION = namespace + MethodName;

        // Adding values to request object
        request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);

        PropertyInfo registerDoctors =new PropertyInfo();

        // doctor name
        Log.v("name", p.getDoctorName().toString());
        registerDoctors.setName("doctorName");
        registerDoctors.setValue(p.getDoctorName());
        registerDoctors.setType(string.class);

        // doctor qualification
        Log.v("qualification", p.getQualification().toString());
        registerDoctors.setName("qualificaion");
        registerDoctors.setValue(p.getQualification());
        registerDoctors.setType(string.class);

        // doctor specialization
        Log.v("specialization", p.getSpecialization().toString());
        registerDoctors.setName("specialization");
        registerDoctors.setValue(p.getSpecialization());
        registerDoctors.setType(string.class);

        // doctor cityId
        Log.v("cityid", p.getCityId().toString());
        registerDoctors.setName("cityId");
        registerDoctors.setValue(p.getCityId());
        registerDoctors.setType(integer.class);

        // doctor areaId
        Log.v("areaid", p.getAreaId().toString());
        registerDoctors.setName("doctorName");
        registerDoctors.setValue(p.getAreaId());
        registerDoctors.setType(integer.class);

        // doctor phoneNo
        Log.v("phone", p.getPhoneNo().toString());
        registerDoctors.setName("phoneNo");
        registerDoctors.setValue(p.getPhoneNo());
        registerDoctors.setType(string.class);

        // doctor mobile1
        Log.v("mobile1", p.getMobile().toString());
        registerDoctors.setName("mobile1");
        registerDoctors.setValue(p.Mobile);
        registerDoctors.setType(string.class);

        // doctor mobile2
        Log.v("mobile2", p.getMobile2().toString());
        registerDoctors.setName("mobile2");
        registerDoctors.setValue(p.getMobile2());
        registerDoctors.setType(string.class);

        request.addProperty(registerDoctors);

        SetEnvelope();

        try {
            // SOAP calling webservice
            androidHttpSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             
            // Got Webservice response
            String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();

            Log.v("add log", result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
           // TODO: handle exception
           return e.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return e.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: try to log the request on the server and have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Send an `ArrayList` PropertyInfo to Server. Change the `server side` to receive `ArrayList` of PropertyIfo. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the query, soap action, namespace, method name and URL at web service properly then use the below method.

```
public static boolean regist(
    String Student_Name,
    String Last_Name,
    String Email_ID,
    String Mobile_Number,
    String Name_Of_The_College,
    String Qualification,
    String Location,
    String Fellowship,
    String Reference,
    String FeeStatus,
    String Slatitude,
    String Slongitude,
    String webMethName
) {
    String registerresponse = "flag";
    Email_ID = "Blank";
    Location = "Blank";

    String URL = "your url";
    String METHOD_NAMEREG = "your method name";
    String NamespaceR = "your namespace", SOAPACTIONREG = "your action";

    try {
        long FellowshipL = Long.valueOf(Fellowship);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NamespaceR, METHOD_NAMEREG);
        // Note: Candidate_Name is property name mentioned in your webservice
        // Student_Name is your value that to be inserted

        request.addProperty("Candidate_Name", Student_Name);
        request.addProperty("LastName", Last_Name);
        request.addProperty("email", Email_ID);
        request.addProperty("Mobile", Mobile_Number);
        request.addProperty("College_Name", Name_Of_The_College);
        request.addProperty("Qualification", Qualification);
        request.addProperty("Location", Location);
        request.addProperty("Fellowshipid", FellowshipL);
        request.addProperty("referenceName", Reference);
        request.addProperty("FeesStatus", FeeStatus);
        request.addProperty("lat", Slatitude);
        request.addProperty("lon", Slongitude);
        // request.addProperty("to", 9);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAPACTIONREG, envelope);
            // Log.i(TAG, "GetAllLoginDetails is running");
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("string value at resp",response.toString());
            registerresponse=response.toString();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("request fail", "> " + t.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Err", "> " + t.getMessage());
    }
    return registerresponse.equals("Record Saved.");
}
```